# Why is $\widetilde{W}$ closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, ultrapowers

We consider $(x _{n})$ a sequence of almost fixed points for $T$ in $C _{0}$. Since $C _{0}$ is weakly compact, we can assume that $(x _{n})$ is weak compact. Also, since the problem of the fixed point is invariant by translations, we can assume that $(x _{n})$ is weakly convergent to 0.
let's consider $\mathscr{U}$ a free ultrafilter on the natural numbers and consider its corresponding ultrapower of Banach space
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{X} = (\ell ^{\infty}(X _{i})/\operatorname{ker}\mathcal{N},\Vert \cdot \Vert),
\end{align*}
where the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is define as
\begin{align*}
\Vert \widetilde{w} \Vert = \lim _{n, \mathscr{U}} \Vert w _{n} \Vert.
\end{align*}
for all $\widetilde{w} \in \widetilde{W}$. Let's call $\widetilde{x}$ is the equivalence class formed by the sequence $(x _{n})$. We define
\begin{align*}
D(\widetilde{w}) = \lim _{m, \mathscr{U}} \left( \lim _{n, \mathscr{U}} \Vert w _{m} - w _{n} \Vert \right).
\end{align*}

this coefficient depends on each $\widetilde{w}$, but not on the representatives that form $\widetilde{w}$.

Let $T: C \to C $ a non-expansive function and $C$ a set of $X$. For the minimal set of 
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{A} = \{ K \subseteq C: \ K \ \mbox{is not empty, weak compact, convex and $T$-invariant}\} 
\end{align*}
called $C _{0}$. We know that $C _{0}$ is closed, convex and $T$-invariant.  We define the set
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{C _{0}} = \{ \widetilde{w}: w _{n} \in C _{0}, \ \mbox{for all} \ n \in \mathbb{N} \} \in \widetilde{X} \mbox{.}
\end{align*} 
Let
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{W} = \left\{ \widetilde{w} \in \widetilde{C _{0}}: \ \Vert \widetilde{w} - \widetilde{x} \Vert \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \ \mbox{and} \ D(\widetilde{w}) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \right\} \mbox{.}
\end{align*}
Why $\widetilde{W}$ is closed?.

Comment: What is $\tilde x$ in the definition of $\widetilde W$?

Comment: is the equivalence class formed by the sequence  $(x _{n})$, where each $x _{n} \in C _{0}$

Comment: I know that.  What I mean is: $\tilde x$ is not a "bound" variable in the definition of $\widetilde W$.  We know what $\tilde w$ is: it varies, and we select those which satisfy the condition.  But $\tilde x$ appears nowhere else, so I don't know, at present, what $\widetilde W$ means.

Comment: $\widetilde{x}$ is the equivalence class formed by the sequende $(x _{n})$, when $(x _{n})$ is a a sequence of almost fixed points for $T$ in $C _{0}$ such that $(x _{n})$ is weakly convergent to 0.

Comment: It would be useful to write a more informative title. And also to say what the objects are even if one can sort of guess  (my guess $C_0$ is the set of real-valued sequences converging to 0 under the sup norm, $T$ is a bounded self-operator of $C_0$). $X_i$ is not defined at all, I have no guess. $C$ is introduced after it's used. Is "a set of $X$" meant to be "a subset of $X$"?